# how to force links or pages to open outside of facebook inapp browser?

Tags: javascript, facebook

First of all there are few posts already but with satisfactory answers so i am posting the same issue again hoping for the solution

[Force links to open outside facebook's inapp browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639644/force-links-to-open-outside-facebooks-inapp-browser)

[Open website link outside of Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478319/open-website-link-outside-of-facebook-app)

The problem is when the user clicks on a website link posted on facebook clicking on the link will open the site in facebook in app browser. I want to detect that the site was opened in facebook's in app browser and then if so force the site or page to open in external browser. I want this ability because there are many things that dont seem to work in facebook's in app browser. I appreciate any input! Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something you can (reliably) detect.

Even if you could, I'm pretty sure there's no way to force the site to open in the device's browser, instead of the in-app browser

Comment: so even detecting if the site is opened in facebook app is not reliable?

Comment: Well, there's the [user agent you can check](https://mpulp.mobi/2012/01/17/funky-user-agent-on-facebook-iphone-app/), but who's to say that won't change?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that worked for me, using Firebase Dynamic Links. It works for Android but not iOS.

I needed this solution so I could upload documents in the messenger in-app browser but couldn't on Android devices.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56143217/3664100